# Modify an entity in sap.ui.table.Table

Tags: sapui5

I want to set a checkbox true in one certain row (In the background).

I use sap.ui.table.Table... Example: I have ten purchase orders and I want to write in an Input field a number ( EBELN) and when I press "Enter" a checkbox in the table ( in the row, where the number = EBELN) should be modify to "True" and the focus should also be on this row. How can I search with a parameter and especially how can I modify it ?

Edit: 
View:

```
<Table id="tableItemsId" enableBusyIndicator="true" rows="{items>/results}"
            selectionMode="None" visibleRowCount="12">
            <toolbar>
                <m:Toolbar>
                    <m:Input id="inEbeln" 
                     placeholder="{i18n>Ebeln}" />
                    <m:Button text="{i18n>Ebeln}" press="onPress" />
                </m:Toolbar>
            </toolbar>
            <columns>
                <Column width="2rem">
                    <m:Label text="{i18n>Check}" />
                    <template>
                        <m:CheckBox
                            selected="{
                            path: '{items>Check}',
                            type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String'
                        }"
                            editable="false" />
                    </template>
                </Column>
                <Column width="6rem">
                    <m:Label text="{i18n>Ebeln}" />
                    <template>
                        <m:Text text="{items>Ebeln}" />
                    </template>
                </Column>
```

onPress:

```
onPress : function(oEvent) {
                var that = this;
                var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
                // Here I want to modify the row in the table "tableItemsId", where Ebeln = "inEbeln"
```

Comment: You can acheive this through binding, but some more detail on your implementation would be welcome :)

Comment: How can i bind it? I have a sap.ui.tabe.Table. In a textfield i write the Ebeln. By pressing enter I want to search for the entry and modify it.      `var sEbeln = this.getView().byId("textfield")
       .getValue();
     var oRouter = sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
     var oTable = this.getView().byId("tableItemsId");` Now i have the table and the sEbeln and how can i search for this ebeln ?

Comment: Bind the text field content to something like {/value} then bind the selected state of the checkbox to something like {= ${/value} === ${number} } (cant give correct code without more information on your implementation :p)

Comment: I've added some code, I do not get it :/ ..

Answer (score 0):

I just created a small [example](https://jsbin.com/gafabi/edit?html,output). In the event handler it loops through all rows compares the entered value with value in the row and sets the checkbox accordingly:

```
onPress : function(event) {
    // this gets the value of the input field
    let value = this.byId("inEbeln").getValue();
    if (!value || value.length === 0) {
        return;
    }
    // loop through all rows and compare the entered value with the value in the row
    let rows = this.byId("table").getRows();
    for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i += 1) {
        let row = rows[i];
        let cells = row.getCells();
        // cells[0] contains the Checkbox
        // cells[1] contains the Text with Ebeln
        cells[0].setSelected(value === cells[1].getText());
    }
}
```